# pam_ldap detecting expiring password

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, pam

I am maintaining some code that uses:
pam_ldap version 186

which compiles against
openldap  2.4.40

We are using Active Directory on Windows 2012 for the LDAP backend.

pam_ldap successfully authenticates when given the correct credentials, and sends back the correct error when the credentials are incorrect.  The issue i am having is when a user is marked as "User must change password at next login", and i login using the correct credentials, it just sends me the Invalid Credentials error.  I looked at the pam_ldap code, added some debugging, and it looks like the code calls "ldap_parse_result" and an LDAPControl structure needs to be filled in, which it then uses to detect for the LDAP_CONTROL_PWEXPIRING flag.  But no matter what i do, the LDAPControl variable points to null.

Is there anything i need to configure on the AD differently, or any additional setup in the code i need to do to detect the "User must change password at next login"?

thank you

-=- adamtg

Answer (score 0):

The "User must change password at next login" setting is set when the `pwdLastSet` attribute is `0`. So you can test for it by checking if that attribute is `0`.

More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adsi/user-must-change-password-at-next-logon